# iPhone Application failing to come back from sigkill

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have no idea if this is intended behaviour, but whenever the application exits (say, the user is double-clicking the home button and pressing on the red dash on the icon) I get the dreaded SIGKILL.

Now, when I try to launch the app again all I get is the old screen state and a frozen (I presume ?) program.

It could be because of clunky memory management, but NSZombieEnabled doesn't seem to agree.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Figured out what is happening:

Apps aren't "supposed" to be closed using the minus button. Instead what we do is save state during **will enter background** calls, state from which we can resume the application later on.

The debugger definitely doesn't like having your app being closed and kinda hangs the OS. To test close/resume/notification features, detach the debugger first.